# Datatable custom processing behaviour

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatables is my web application. I have enabled the drop down where the user can select the number of entries they wish to see.

At the moment I have processing message enabled when the user selects the number of entries to display.

What I would like to do is instead of showing the processing message I would like a button on my page (already exists with an id) to be disabled and show some other text like "Loading" (i.e. override the custom processing behaviour). Then once the processing is finished I would like the button to return back to it's original state (i.e. enabled with original text).

Is this possible and how would I do it? Here is my current datatable initialisation code.

```
$('#search-results-table').dataTable({
    'bServerSide': true,                                // user server side processing
    'sAjaxSource': searchResultsTableAjaxServletUrl,    // load data from an external source                
    'bProcessing': true,                                // enable the processing indicator whilst table is loading
    'deferRender': true,
    'searching': false,                                 // disable search box
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers', 
    'oLanguage': {
        'sEmptyTable': 'Items not found.'
    },          
    'fnServerData': function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (data) {                
            //there was a web service error
            if ('errorMessage' in data) {
                $('div#errorMessage h2').html(data.errorMessage);
                    fnCallback({ 'aaData': [], 'iTotalDisplayRecords': 0, 'iTotalRecords': 0, 'sColumns': null, 'sEcho': 1});
            }
            // only if expected json array is returned go ahead and load
            if (('aaData' in data)) {
                fnCallback(data);
            }
        })
        .fail(function() { 
            $('div#errorMessage h2').html('Search service unavailable, please contact IT support or try again later');
                fnCallback({ 'aaData': [], 'iTotalDisplayRecords': 0, 'iTotalRecords': 0, 'sColumns': null, 'sEcho': 1});            
        });
    },
    'initComplete': function(settings, json) {
        enableFields('#searchButton');
    },                          
    'aoColumnDefs':[{  
        'aTargets': [ 4 ], 
        'mRender': function ( data, type, full )  {
            return  '<a href="javascript:setItemNumber(' + data + ');">' + data + '</a>';
        }
    }],              
    'aoColumns': [
        {'mDataProp':'itemDescription','bSortable':false,sDefaultContent:'','sWidth':'40%'},
        {'mDataProp':'size','bSortable':false,'sClass':'center',sDefaultContent:'','sWidth':'15%'},   
        {'mDataProp':'colour','bSortable':false,'sClass':'center',sDefaultContent:'','sWidth':'15%'},                     
        {'mDataProp':'supplyStyle','bSortable':false,'sClass':'center',sDefaultContent:'','sWidth':'15%'},
        {'mDataProp':'itemNumber','bSortable':false,'sClass':'center',sDefaultContent:'','sWidth':'15%'}
   ]
```

});

Comment: I think you can do this with jquery. Add a .gif image of loading . Intially hide  it.Once your processing starts make the image visible ,once you complete your table loading ,hide that image. This worked with me

Comment: Hi. Where I datatables event code do I need to put my hide and show code? What handlers do I add

Comment: Firstly you need to show the image when you call is initiated. So , the image shows when the call is being processed and once the process gets completed, .complete(function() get executed where you put your hide code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to my datatables code to override the default behaviour of the processing function. I also set bProcessing to false.

```
 $('#search-results-table')  .on('processing.dt',function( e, settings, processing ){
     if (processing){
             disableSearchButton();
     }else {
             enableSearchButton();
     }
     } )
```